# Pymongo: while returning the data through a def only returns one row

Tags: pymongo

```
def av():
for row in info.aggregate([{"$project": {"firstname": 1}}]):
    list=[]
    list.append(row)
    list=str(list)
    return list
print(av())
```

here, if instead of writing 'return list' I write 'print (list)' it gives me all the data I needed
but, if I try to return it. the output gives only the first row of the data(collection)
As i want to call the function later in the program to give if conditions to check whether the given output is present in the data or not
it is a must that i return the and not print.
Please tell me what i am missing
or is there a better way do the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is return exit the for loop in the first iteration, meanwhile print do not.
Write return list at the same level than the for-loop. moreover you empty the list everytime, define it before the loop.

```
 def av():
    list=[]
    for row in info.aggregate([{"$project": {"firstname": 1}}]):
        list.append(row)
    list=str(list)
    return list
 print(av())
```